# Monte Carlo simulation t test

Tags: montecarlo, rscript

I’m struggling with working out a simulation of a Monte Carlo study in which I have to compare a two sample t-test  under 2 situations (var= equal vs var is not equal) (H0: µ1=µ2). I want to calculate the type 1 error (α= .05) I started with the creation of 2 sample out of a normal distribution under the condition of the same σ. I can do the same but with differen σ. I can perform the t-tests but I do not get to the point of performing the Monte Carlo simulations. Can anybody help me?

```
    >NormalSample <- function(n1,n2)
    >{S1<-rnorm(n1, mean=50, sd=10)
    >S2<- rnorm(n2, mean=50, sd= 10)
    >return (as.data.frame(cbind(S1,S2)))
    >}
    >Sample1<-NormalSample(10,10)
    >ttest1<-(t.test (Sample1$S1,Sample1$S2, 
    >alternative="two.sided",var.equal=FALSE)
    >ttest2<-t.test (Sample1$S1,Sample1$S2, var.equal = TRUE)
    >ttest1
    >ttest2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this can help?
Anyone who can confirm or who can correct?

```
>n1 <- 100
>n2<- 100
>cnt <- 0
>for(i in 1:10000)
 {
>x1 <- rnorm(n1,0,1)
>x2 <- rnorm(n2, , 1)
>pval <- t.test(x1,x2, alternative="two.sided", var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
>if(pval < 0.05) cnt <- cnt +1
>}
>cnt/10000
```

Comment: You shouldn't really post an answer unless it's correct - otherwise it turns into another question to answer. Make sure you test all your code before submitting it as an answer. Additionally, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.